# dompdf exclude menu and footer

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hy,
I use dompdf and when generating the pdf, the respective menu and the footer from the "mother" page are included. I don't know where to edit the code to exclude the menu and footer.

Code controller:

```
  function export_invoice($param1 = 'export' ) {
  $page_data['action']   = $param1;
  $page_data['page_name'] = 'export_invoice';
  $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('export_invoice');
  $this->load->view('frontend/'.get_frontend_settings('theme').'/index', $page_data);
  $html1 =$this->load->view('frontend/'.get_frontend_settings('theme').'/index',$page_data, true);
  $html = mb_convert_encoding($html1, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
  $this->pdf->loadHtml($html);
  $this->pdf->set_paper("a5", "portrait" ); //landscape
  $this->pdf->render();
  // FILE DOWNLOADING CODES
  $url = current_url();
  $str = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);
  $str1=$str;
 $fileName = 'Invoice-'.$str.'.pdf';
 $this->pdf->stream($fileName, array("Attachment" => 0)); //initial era 1 pentru descarcare si 0 pentru preview in broswer
}
```

And view:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PDF Output</title>
        <style>
            /* your style here */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        {contents}
    </body>
</html>
```

[Image from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXydy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I use css and it works with:

```
.menu-area{display: none;}
```